# vbscript how to check if txt file exists and whe not create empty one

Tags: vbscript, hta

How can i check with vbscript if the txt file in C:\Temp\CAD_Kunde.txt exists and when it does not exist it should be empty created.

Edit:
I get an error (Expected Statement on Line 11 Char 1 when i use this:

```
   <SCRIPT Language="VBScript"> 
        Sub Window_OnLoad
 //Line 11 is the one below:
    Option Explicit  
    Dim oFSO, oTxtFile   
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")     
    If oFSO.FileExists("C:\Temp\CAD_Kunde.txt")  then
           Msgbox "File Exist" 
    Else 
          Set oTxtFile = oFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Temp\CAD_Kunde.txt")  
          Msgbox "File Created" 
    End If 

    End Sub
    </script>
```

Comment: Place the Option explicit line before the Sub line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<SCRIPT Language="VBScript">
Sub Window_OnLoad
Option Explicit 
Dim oTxtFile 
With (CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"))
  If .FileExists("C:\Temp\CAD_Kunde.txt") Then
    Msgbox "File Exist"
  Else 
    Set oTxtFile = .CreateTextFile("C:\Temp\CAD_Kunde.txt")
    Msgbox "File Created" 
  End If 
End With
End Sub
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its Easy

```
Option Explicit 
Dim oFSO, oTxtFile


Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 



If oFSO.FileExists("C:\Temp\CAD_Kunde.txt")  Then
Msgbox "File Exist"
Else 
Set oTxtFile = oFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Temp\CAD_Kunde.txt") 
Msgbox "File Created"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about discriminating between exist/not exists and just want to ensure one is present, you can

```
set f = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("c:\blabla", 1, true)
f.close()
```