# How can I make a VBScript create text files in the downloads folder?

Tags: vbscript

I want to make a VBScript create a text file the downloads folder but I can't figure out how to do it.
Any help?

Comment: This may help you:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198810/creating-and-writing-lines-to-a-file

Comment: If you're working with `WScript`, try this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465278/vbscript-how-to-check-if-txt-file-exists-and-whe-not-create-empty-one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465278/vbscript-how-to-check-if-txt-file-exists-and-whe-not-create-empty-one)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Temporary folder by this way :

```
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
TempFolder = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
```

---

And the entire vbscript can be written as below to create a text file into the temporary folder :

```
Option Explicit
Dim ws,fso,TempFolder,FileFullPath,FileName,objFile
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
TempFolder = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
FileName = "testfile.txt"
FileFullPath = TempFolder & "\" & FileName
wscript.echo "The Temparary folder is located : " & vbCrlf & TempFolder
wscript.echo "The Full Path of the text file is : " & vbCrlf & FileFullPath
Set objFile = fso.CreateTextFile(FileFullPath, True)
' Write something into text file
objFile.WriteLine("This is a test.")
objFile.Close
' If we want to open the text file created with Notepad
ws.run "Notepad " & FileFullPath
```

---

The download folder can be found here :

```
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
DownloadFolder = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%userprofile%") & "\Downloads"
wscript.echo DownloadFolder
```

---

And the entire script for the creation of a text file in the Download folder :

```
Option Explicit
Dim ws,fso,DownloadFolder,FileFullPath,FileName,objFile
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
DownloadFolder = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%userprofile%") & "\Downloads"
FileName = "testfile.txt"
FileFullPath = DownloadFolder & "\" & FileName
wscript.echo "The Download folder is located : " & vbCrlf & DownloadFolder
wscript.echo "The Full Path of the text file is : " & vbCrlf & FileFullPath
Set objFile = fso.CreateTextFile(FileFullPath, True)
' Write something into text file
objFile.WriteLine("This is a test.")
objFile.Close
' If we want to open the text file created with Notepad
ws.run "Notepad " & FileFullPath
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it create a new text file when you run the file again instead of overwriting it?

Answer (score -1):

**Create Text File in Documents**

```
Option Explicit

Const FileName = "New.txt"

Dim wss: Set wss = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim FolderPath: FolderPath = wss.SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")

Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim FilePath: FilePath = fso.BuildPath(FolderPath, FileName)
Dim fsoFile:Set fsoFile = fso.CreateTextFile(FilePath, True)
fsoFile.Close
```

**Get Documents Folder Path**

```
Option Explicit

Dim wss: Set wss = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim FolderPath: FolderPath = wss.SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")

MsgBox "Your documents folder is located in '" _
    & Folderpath & "'.", vbInformation, "Documents"

Dim RunString: RunString = "explorer.exe /e," & FolderPath
wss.Run RunString
```